# Bash: Running the same program over multiple cores

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have access to a machine where I have access to 10 of the cores -- and I would like to actually use them. What I am used to doing on my own machine would be something like this:

```
for f in *.fa; do
  myProgram (options) "./$f" "./$f.tmp"
done
```

I have 10 files I'd like to do this on -- let's call them blah00.fa, blah01.fa, ... blah09.fa.

The problem with this approach is that myProgram only uses 1 core at a time, and doing it like this on the multi-core machine I'd be using 1 core at a time 10 times, so I wouldn't be using my mahcine to its max capability.

How could I change my script so that it runs all 10 of my .fa files at the same time? I looked at [Run a looped process in bash across multiple cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907406/run-a-looped-process-in-bash-across-multiple-cores) but I couldn't get the command from that to do what I wanted exactly.

Comment: You tried `gnu parallel`? What didn't work for you?

Comment: Have you tried using gnu parallel suggestion in that answer?

Comment: `seq 0 10 | parallel myProgram -opt1 -opt2 ./blah{}.fa ./blah{}.tmp`

Comment: Yes, I tried using parallel. Problem: on the machine with many cores it's not installed and I have no sudo access so can't use parallel. :(

Comment: You don't need to be root to install it; download the source and run `./configure --prefix=${HOME}; make; make install` to install it in your home directory.

Comment: @JonathanDursi - add that as an answer and I'll upvote

Comment: Showed the sys admin of the machine this and this convinced him to put parallel on the machine -- thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: You can use `taskset -c <coreid> myProgram ... &` to spawn processes in the background, bound to specific CPU cores. That only requires `schedutils` installed (which are by default), not `parallels`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use

```
for f in *.fa; do
    myProgram (options) "./$f" "./$f.tmp" &
done
wait
```

which would start all of you jobs in parallel, then wait until they *all* complete before moving on. In the case where you have more jobs than cores, you would start all of them and let your OS scheduler worry about swapping processes in an out.

One modification is to start 10 jobs at a time

```
count=0
for f in *.fa; do
    myProgram (options) "./$f" "./$f.tmp" &
    (( count ++ ))        
    if (( count = 10 )); then
        wait
        count=0
    fi
done
```

but this is inferior to using `parallel` because you can't start new jobs as old ones finish, and you also can't detect if an older job finished before you manage to start 10 jobs. `wait` allows you to wait on a single particular process or *all* background processes, but doesn't let you know when any one of an arbitrary set of background processes complete.

Comment: Next version of Bash will have an option for that (`wait -n`). Currently you can do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/ormaaj/3911059) but it's a bit racy due to some bugs that will also be fixed in the next version.

Answer (score 8):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
parallel myProgram (options) {} {.}.tmp ::: *.fa
```

From: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

= Full installation =

Full installation of GNU Parallel is as simple as:

```
./configure && make && make install
```

If you are not root you can add ~/bin to your path and install in
~/bin and ~/share:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install
```

Or if your system lacks 'make' you can simply copy src/parallel
src/sem src/niceload src/sql to a dir in your path.

= Minimal installation =

If you just need parallel and do not have 'make' installed (maybe the
system is old or Microsoft Windows):

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
cp parallel sem
mv parallel sem dir-in-your-$PATH/bin/
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Answer (score 0):

```
# Wait while instance count less than $3, run additional instance and exit
function runParallel () {
    cmd=$1
    args=$2
    number=$3
    currNumber="1024"
    while true ; do
        currNumber=`ps -e | grep -v "grep" | grep " $1$" | wc -l`
        if [ $currNumber -lt $number ] ; then
            break
        fi
        sleep 1
    done
    echo "run: $cmd $args"
    $cmd $args &
}

loop=0
# We will run 12 sleep commands for 10 seconds each 
# and only five of them will work simultaneously
while [ $loop -ne 12 ] ; do
    runParallel "sleep" 10 5
    loop=`expr $loop + 1`
done
```