# How to run few nohup in same time?

Tags: linux, bash, nohup

I have tool trimmings content from file. I need to use it on 33 files. One file is processing 2 hours.
I want to try run it 33 Times on same tame coz one instance used one core, on my machine I have 128 cores.

So I wrote script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/ab/raw/*

for f in $FILES
do
  base = ${f##*/}
  nohup /home/ab/trimmer -a /home/ab/trimmer/adapters.fa -o "OUT$base" $f
done
```

So main line:
I run trimmer, -a it's file with patterns to delete, -o it's new file as outpu (OUT+basename) and last $f is processing file.

My intention was that the script would run separate tasks for each file. 
But unfortunately, after run it, only one nohup will be launched. In htop it's still only one core working at 100%.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Add `&` at the end of your command.

Comment: U mean after $f?

Comment: Yep `nohup /home/ab/trimmer -a /home/ab/trimmer/adapters.fa -o "OUT$base" $f &`

Comment: Thanks, I do that, and yes, I got 33 nohup output but it's still works on one core :/ So I don't know if becasue only one nohup is running or all nohups are running on one core.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343561/bash-running-the-same-program-over-multiple-cores) will help.

Comment: You probably don't want `nohup`, just `&` unless you really want them to keep running if the console dies. Especially if you want to use `wait`